# Get visibly user input from terminal, hide it after \n

Tags: c, terminal

How to get user input with fgets to stdin so you can see what you type, then after enter \n it gets hidden/flushed in terminal in C?

Comment: This will depend on your terminal environment and whether or not it supports such a thing - an old fashioned teletype sure wouldn't, for example! If you fill in some details about what your environment is here, it will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: That cannot be done in a portable way

Comment: Clear the terminal screen?